# jasmine unit test for $window.location

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to jasmine, could some one hwlp to write jasmine unit test for below code :

```
otherwise({redirectTo:function(){
    if(CONTEXTUAL_START_VIEW) {
        return ($window.location.href.indexOf('/flight/') || $window.location.href.indexOf('/air/')) > -1  ? '/air' : '/hotel';
    }
    else {
        return '/hotel';
    }
}});
```

i tried this way below:

```
describe("Routing to air home", function() {
    var scope, element, compile, $window, $location;
    var windowObj = {location: {href: {indexOf: `jasmine.createSpy()}}};`
    $location = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', ['path']);
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$window', windowObj);
    }));
    beforeEach(module('hotelApp.routing'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, _$window_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $window = _$window_;
  }));
it("should redirect to /air when /flight/ or /air/ otherwise to default hotel", function() {
   scope.CONTEXTUAL_START_VIEW = true;
   $location.path("/");
   scope.$digest();
   expect($location).toBeDefined();
   expect(windowObj.location.href.indexOf('/flight')).toBeUndefined();
   expect($location.path()).toEqual();
   });
});
```

Comment: what have you tried? Have you tried to expect some $httpBackend get requests??

Comment: @panzhuli i didn't try any for now. how do i proceed?

Comment: well, you'll have to try something first! I can work with a plunkr but can't write your tests for you ;)